# Nvidia Cg 3.0 Manual/Documentation?

Tags: documentation, cg

I can only find a user's manual for Cg 1.4 from Sept 2005, and the Cg Tutorial from earlier than that. Cg is now on version 3 and I'm wondering about all the new profiles and tech that must be in it... Anyone got some links?

Comment: Actually the reference manual is up to date in the nvidia site [Cg 3.0 Reference Manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/Cg_3.0/Cg-3.0_February2011_ReferenceManual.pdf), which i believe is where you can get most of the information you want. Doesn't it come with the Cg installation?

Comment: Okay, I did see that too, but being so manpage-esque I was put off by it. So all up-to-date relevant information can be found in this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference manual is up to date in the nvidia site [Cg 3.0 Reference Manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/Cg_3.0/Cg-3.0_February2011_ReferenceManual.pdf), which i believe is where you can get most of the information you want. It does contain very detailed data of everything you can do with Cg, I don't think there's something missing there, but it may be hard to read at first as it's just a reference for all the technical aspects of it, you will hardly find something like a tutorial in it, perhaps there is some very small examples to explain some concepts (I'm gonna read some now it looks interesting).

EDIT: 
The manual doesn't seem to be that tough as I expected, if you have some experience with Cg or something similar already. I downloaded everything from the [Cg Toolkit Download](http://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit-download) page. There it also mentions the users manuals and the demo tutorials were not updated, I believe you may find more updated tutorials on the web.

and this is [The Cg Tutorial](http://developer.nvidia.com/node/76) book, it may be useful for people interested in Cg

Comment: Okay, it looks like they just haven't updated the tutorial (which is great at explaining everything) for all the newer features yet.